# Applescript editor not responding

Tags: applescript, itunes, itunesartwork

I did the following script in order to identify itunes songs that doesn't have artwork. It's based on other script that I found in net.

```
tell application "iTunes"
   repeat with a in every track of playlist "Library"
      if not (exists (artwork 1 of a)) then
         add (get location of a) to (playlist "noart")
      end if
   end repeat
end tell
```

It seems to be working, it compiles well, and because I can that it in event log windows:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    count every track of playlist "Library"
        --> 10684
    exists artwork 1 of item 1 of every track of playlist "Library"
        --> true
    exists artwork 1 of item 2 of every track of playlist "Library"
        --> true
```

But after 4 hundred tracks, it starts to run slowly, and applescript stops responding after one thousand tracks.

I thought that maybe I could be exhausting my mac memory, but in Activity Monitor, I can see that Applescript is consuming 100% CPU and less than 50MB of memory. I'm running macos 10.7.4 on a macbook pro (i7 with 4GB ram).

As you can see my itunes library has 10684 tracks. It's not a small library, but it's not a huge one.

Does anyone has any advice? Or a script to identify tracks without artwork?

TIA,

Bob

Comment: Info:
When you iterate over a long list, don't use the "event log window", because "Applescript editor" will not respond if the number of characters in the "event log window" is too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use. My main suggestion would be to use "duplicate" instead of "add" and then you do not need to get the location of a track. Also you'll see I'm using "a reference to" most things which makes it work faster. I also create the "no artwork" playlist with a time stamp on-the-fly so I can see when I ran the script.

```
set d to current date
set missingTracksCount to 0
tell application "iTunes"
    set isFixedIndexing to fixed indexing
    if not isFixedIndexing then set fixed indexing to true

    -- make a new playlist to hold the tracks
    set newPlaylist to make new playlist
    set name of newPlaylist to "No Art - " & month of d & " " & day of d & " " & time string of d

    set mainPlaylist to a reference to playlist "Library"
    set noArtworkPlaylist to a reference to newPlaylist

    set trackCount to count of tracks of mainPlaylist
    repeat with i from 1 to trackCount
        set trackRef to (a reference to (track i of mainPlaylist))
        if (count of artworks of trackRef) is less than 1 then
            duplicate trackRef to noArtworkPlaylist
            set missingTracksCount to missingTracksCount + 1
        end if
    end repeat

    if not isFixedIndexing then set fixed indexing to isFixedIndexing

    display dialog "Finished!" & return & (missingTracksCount as text) & " tracks didn't have artwork." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon note giving up after 5
end tell
```

Comment: It scanned my library in less then 30 seconds... I'll try to change my script in onder to identify wich line is holding it.